# jQuery plugin which lets users draw rectangles in a div works in basic setup, but not when implemented in my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [Boxer plugin](http://jsbin.com/azare/) to allow the user to draw rectangles in a div. I've got it working in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8vnw/).

But I can't get it working in [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/7WgdH/), which is how I would be using it. I think it may be because of the CSS styling? Can anyone tell why it doesn't work?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the plug-in was using jQueryUI 1.7.2, and in the second example you were using the jQueryUI 1.8 Framework, some things are incompatible, see this document on how to update the plug-in to match the new framework

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide

Comment: Ah, didn't realise. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `<script>` declarations for jQuery and jQuery UI:  I updated the `head` of your sample:

```
<head>
    <title>Page</title>  
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Sometimes it's the simplest things that get ya :)

Updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/q75J7/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think with jsFiddle you can choose to load jQuery and jQuery UI in the sidebar on the left, which is what I've done in the examples in the original question. Explicitly linking the files like you've done doesn't seem to change anything, as the rectangles still cannot be drawn onto the canvas div

Comment: Though it turns out, after reading Cubed Eye Studios' answer, you were correct, because I was loading the newer version of jQuery UI :)